# Create a word and number password in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, password-generator

I have attempted to create something that resembles a password generator, the first part being a word and the second part being a 2-digit number. However, I receive an index error whenever I run this program. Any solutions?

```
import urllib.request
import random



word_url = "https://donyinc.weebly.com/uploads/4/2/1/7/42178775/part1.txt"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(word_url)
long_txt = response.read().decode()
words = long_txt.splitlines()

upper_words = [word for word in words if word[0].isupper()]
name_words  = [word for word in upper_words if not word.isupper()]
one_name = ' '.join([name_words[random.randint(0, len(name_words))] for i in range(1)])


def rand_name():
   name = ' '.join([name_words[random.randint(0, len(name_words))] for i in range(1)])
   return name


for n in range(10):
    name = rand_name()

#part 2

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#$%^&*"
no_length = 2
myno = ""

for i in range(no_length):
    next_index = random.randrange(len(alphabet))
    myno = myno + alphabet[next_index]

print(name)+(no)

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Answer (score 2):

When I run your code, both `upper_words` and `name_words` are empty. So, `random.randint(0, len(name_words))` always returns `0`, and the code tries to access the element at index `0` of `name_words`. Because `name_words` is empty, this raises an `IndexError`.